# Issues with friend name injection

Tags: c++, friend

I attempted to get friend name injection to work with the following snippet:

```
struct foo
{
  friend foo f() { return {}; }
};

int main()
{
  auto x = f();
  return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
test.cc:8:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'f'
  auto x = f();
           ^
1 error generated.
```

I have to declare `f` in the outer namespace for the error to vanish.

The standard has an explanation in paragraph 3 of §7.3.1.2:

> If a friend declaration in a
>   non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template97 the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. The friend declaration does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or qualified lookup (3.4.3). [Note: The name of the friend will be visible in its namespace **if a matching declaration is provided at namespace scope (either before or after the class definition granting friendship)**. — end note ]

My question: why do we need an extra declaration of `f` at namespace scope for this to compile? Does it have to do with ADL? Is there a (hacky) way around this requirement?

Comment: If you can force ADL, then it will find `f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force ADL:

```
struct foo {
  friend foo f(foo *) { return {}; }
};

int main()
{
  auto x = f((foo *) 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiles with g++ 4.9.0 and clang++ 3.4. Of course, might not be practical.

ADDENDUM: Thanks to Richard Hodges, here is another possible workaround, but it might be a g++ 4.9.0 bug. There are differences between clang++ and g++. I'll try to look into what the standard says, if I have time. If the OP wants to post this as a new question asking about which compiler is wrong, please do.

```
struct foo {
  friend foo f1() { return {}; }
  friend foo f2(foo *) { return {}; }
  template<typename T = void>
  friend foo f3() { return {}; }
};

int main()
{
  auto x1 = f1(); // Error, f1() not visible.
  auto x2 = f2((foo *) 0); // Force ADL.
  auto x3 = f3<void>(); // Use template, okay with g++, fails with clang++.
  auto x4 = f3(); // Use template with default param, okay with g++, fails with clang++.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: struct foo
{
  template<typename T> friend foo f() { return {}; }
};

int main()
{
  auto x = f<void>();
  return 0;
}

also compiles - equally horrible.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to add a bit more template magic to make `f3` work with generically.

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin: Not sure if you saw the version with the default template argument or not, since I was making some edits. That one looks like it works transparently, but might be a g++ bug.

Comment: Okay, a quick search of the standard didn't turn up anything. It seems like a g++ bug. So the question is whether or not a template friend function definition is available for lookup without a matching declaration in namespace scope. Compilers disagree. Post this as a new question, if you want a definitive answer.

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin: Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452015/is-a-friend-function-template-defined-in-the-class-available-for-lookup-clang

Answer (score -2):

friend works on a declaration, not a definition.

```
struct foo
{
  friend foo f();
};

foo f() { return {}; }

int main()
{
  auto x = f();
  return 0;
}
```

compiles

Comment: You can define a function in a friend. Try it.

Comment: if the returned type is complete. In the case of the definition of f() above, foo is not a complete type so it can't compile f() (which constructs one).

Comment: See the code in the answer that I posted. It compiles and runs.

Comment: Oh, interesting... and a little bit broken!